# Not able to switch user in ansible

Tags: ansible, redhat

We have a system where we have user A and user B. We can switch to user B from A using "sudo su" command only. Direct login to B user is not allowed.

Now From Ansible master, we can login to A user (as ansible remote user) successfully. Our use case is, We have to run some commands as user B using ansible. But we are failing to switch to B user and run those commands.

Our yml file looks like -

## Module to copy java to the target host.

```
- name: Copying Java jdk1.8.0_192
  remote_user: A
  become_user: B
  become: true
  become_method: su
  copy:
    src: /etc/ansible/jboss7-cluster/raw_template/jdk1.8.0_192.zip
    dest: "{{ java_install_dir }}"
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I believe the `become_method` should be the default `sudo`. Have you tried using that? If so, what is the result? Can you copy/paste the result here?

Also, can you try to run an ad hoc command against the host, and post the result here?

Something like this:
`ansible -i inventory.ini -u A --become --become-user B -m ping myhost`

And one more thing: note that there are [some restrictions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user) when using `become` to switch to a non-privileged user:

"In addition to the additional means of doing this securely, Ansible 2.1 also makes it harder to unknowingly do this insecurely. Whereas in Ansible 2.0.x and below, Ansible will silently allow the insecure behaviour if it was unable to find another way to share the files with the unprivileged user, in Ansible 2.1 and above Ansible defaults to issuing an error if it can’t do this securely. If you can’t make any of the changes above to resolve the problem, and you decide that the machine you’re running on is secure enough for the modules you want to run there to be world readable, you can turn on allow_world_readable_tmpfiles in the ansible.cfg file. Setting allow_world_readable_tmpfiles will change this from an error into a warning and allow the task to run as it did prior to 2.1."

And just as a side note: please avoid using `sudo su` - use `sudo -i`, or at least `sudo su -` . These will populate the environment correctly, unlike `sudo su`. For a fun read about why you want this, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su).